# Problem with the existence of a iterated integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

Let $$
F(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
1 &\mbox{ if } x\in\mathbb{Q},\\
0 &\mbox{ if } x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$
Then, $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}F(x,y)dydx$ exists?\
I'm convinced that this integral does not exists, because if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ then the integral $\int_{0}^{1}F(x,y)dy=1$ and 0 in the other case but my proffesor told me that it exists since there is no dependence on the variable y. I don`t know if he told me that just to confuse me or is actually true...

Comment: What type of integral are you using? Riemann? Lebesgue? The answer depends on this.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Riemann, that's why I think that the integral doesn't exists

Comment: Then yes, by the reasoning you have given (and some extra work) it doesn't exist.